# Is there a good free DWG viewer for Mac OS X?

Tags: applications

There are new Autodesk products (AutoCAD LT or similar) for Mac OS and iOS, but I couldn't find a simple free DWG viewer for Mac.

Answer (score 5):

[AutoCAD WS](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/autocad-ws/id454730552?mt=12) is a free app on the Mac App Store. I've never tried it.

Comment: Has 16MB file size limit. And you have to register to Autodesk (or already have their account). Otherwise seemed okay.

Answer (score 5):

### A360 Viewer

AutoCAD's A360 Viewer is a browser based tool for viewing `DWG` files:

> [**A360 Viewer**](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/) Free online viewer - View designs in more than 50 file formats, including .dwg, right in your browser—no downloads or plug-ins needed.

Edit: 2021-11-26: A360 viewer requires Autodesk subscription to be able to upload and view .dwg files.

### LibreCAD

[LibreCAD](https://librecad.org) is open source, free, and can read and write `DWG` files.

[image: LibreCAD]

Answer (score 2):

The free [eDrawings Viewer for Mac](http://www.edrawingsviewer.com/) claims to be able to read and display DWG files. The [Microspot DWG Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Microspot-DWG-Viewer/3000-2192_4-10549118.html) also provides support for DWG files.

I don't have any DWG files to test these two products on at the moment, but they're worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I did try the eDrawings Viewer for Mac but it doesn't allow do measurements and printing is not great neither.
I finally found viewer which has all what I was looking for - ZWCAD Viewer. Get it from "cnet.com" as I couldn't find it on the ZWSOFT home page.

Comment: ZWSOFT appears to be out of business.

Answer (score 1):

I've found "Fast Cad Reader" on Mac App Store. It is incredibly fast and easy to use. It is only for simple DWG file reading, does not have pro features but I think it is far by the best -just view- app available for mac.

https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/fast-cad-reader/id1484905765?mt=12